# Giving the initial parameter from external to Statefulwidget

Tags: flutter

I want to make `Page Widget` with string "mytitle","Anime"

It might be too simple question but it is very confusing for me the relationship of `StatefulWidget` and `State`

```
return Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
     NoAnimationMaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context,"mytitle","Anime") => AnimePage()));

class AnimePage extends StatefulWidget {
  AnimePage({Key key, this.title, this.video}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final String video;

  @override
  _AnimePageState createState() => _AnimePageState();
}

class _AnimePageState extends State<AnimePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.video) //want to show `Anime` here
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```dart
   return Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      NoAnimationMaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => AnimePage(
          // pass your parameter values
          title: 'My Anime',
          video: YOUR_VIDEO_PARAM,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thank you it works. and simpe to understand. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add the constructor on the State, like this...

```
class AnimePage extends StatefulWidget {
  AnimePage({Key key, this.title, this.video}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final String video;

  @override
  _AnimePageState createState() => _AnimePageState(title,video);
}

class _AnimePageState extends State<AnimePage> {
  final String title;
  final String video;

  _AnimePageState(this.title,this.video);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.video) //want to show `Anime` here
    };
```

I hope that was what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you very much, but in my case , I don't use constructor in `_AnimePageState`,but it works.